# Eloquent relations - add (but don't save) to belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to create en Eloquent model without saving it to the database right away.  I would, however, like to include all relationships so that with a single "push()" call I could save the entire structure.

The below example shows what I am trying to to.  I have the following relationships set up:

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}

class Tag extends Eloquent
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }
}
```

Pretty standard, a post can have many tags, and a tag can belong to many posts.

I understand I can simply do this now:

```
//save the post
$post = new Post;
$post->save();

//assign the tag
$post->tags()->save($tag);
```

However, what I really am looking for is:

```
//create the post
$post = new Post;

//assign the tag (without saving anything yet!)
$post->tags()->add($tag);

//save the whole thing
$post->push();
```

The relevant docs are [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) but it seems there is no mention of "add" on belongsToMany rather than "save".

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I dont think that is possible. Post and tags are related in such a way that tag has post_id if I am not mistaken, and id is generated only when post are saved and only then can tag be related to post.

Comment: Sure - actually both post_id and tag_id will be in post_tag table, but point taken.  I would still have thought this would be possible.  From an implementation perspective, I guess it would need to simply create the parents before the pivots.  So certainly possible - but perhaps not implemented currently.

Comment: It seems that it might be possible if you have pivot table like such and you use some other identifiers as foreign keys instead of using generated id. With that in place, you can first save pivot table and then save posts and related tags.

Comment: So what I am hearing is that as I suspected, laravel does not currently have the functionality to do this?  I would need to write a custom save function to do this in the right order?

Comment: You might be able to do it in Laravel way, I am not that experienced with laravel, but there should be a way out.

Comment: Why the downvotes???

Comment: I didnt, may be I can upvote for compensation :), your question seem legit to me, why would I downvote

Comment: Thanks!  It would be nice of those people who do downvote to let OPs know why so that the question can be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy, when you understand what

```
$post->tags()->add($tag);
```

does. This is going to access the tags relationship ala query builder but what you're looking to do simply add tag/s to your post.

Laravel doesn't have a built in way to handle this but you could easily approach it like so:

See below

```
$post->addTag($tag); // Adding a tag to our tag array


protected $attributes = [
   'tags' => [],    
];

//type hint a tag and push the tag into our tags attribute
public function addTag(Tag $tag) { 
   array_push($this->attributes['tags'], $tag);
}


//Iterate over the tags and attach them to our Post model, 
also save the post model after.

public function push() {
  return collect($this->attributes['tags'])->each(function($tag){
     $this->attach($tag);
  });
  $this->save();
}
```

I haven't tested the code but this will hopefully get you set on the right path. I would also be interested in knowing why you have found your self pushing towards this implementation? I haven't found a use case for something like this before and may be able to assist you find a more standardised way of handling your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Perhaps you are right and this is not a standard approach.  The idea was to not only deal with the basic CRUD methods when implementing a controller, but to convert everything to a standard model internally.  This could then either be saved, have some actions performed on, thrown away, or perhaps even directly use this on views without saving anything at all.  If I did want to store, I could simply just push the entire model to the DB.  What would be the more standard approach?

Comment: I see I see, so in the above example – You would be passing a pre-populated un-persisted Post object around. I tend to persist everything or use a State Persistence Pattern in my front end (See vuex.vuejs.org) for things like this, then if the user wants to "Push" they just chuck the Post object from the front end to the API, it's a similar idea to what you're doing here without a framework on the front end. Maybe you're in a place where you need something more from your web stack? Seems like using Laravel for this is overkill when it's easier maintained on the front end. Just food for thought

Comment: Actually the post and tags example is not in my application at all.  It was simply to demonstrate what I was trying to do.  Put simply, I am playing with the idea that the Eloquent model is more than just a way to persist my data, with the ability to store with ease when needed.  As you say in your answer, I believe with some customization of the models, it is still very possible, I just need customize each class a little to handle the pivots.  But you have got me considering whether or not its all necessary, so thank you for that!

Comment: How does this work when loading an already saved model and it's relationships? (your _attributes won't get populated)  I need to do something similar to handle one-time configurations of objects or 'saved' configuration of objects. I was thinking I could override save() to handle your _attributes[] method of temporarily storing relations, but how do you populate _attributes[] when it loads from the db? Or should I just create an accessor that checks both when returning my relations?